# Detecting changes to JavaScript values from C/Obj-C in JavaScriptCore

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa, javascriptcore

Is there a uniform way to detect changes to VM state in JavaScriptCore from the host program? I'm currently using the new Obj-C API, but I don't mind having to switch to the standard WebKit APIs if it give me what I want.

Ideally I'd be able to do something like this:

```
JSContext *ctx = [JSContext new];
[ctx registerMythicalChangeWatcher:aBlockOrDelegate];
[ctx evaluateScript:@"var deez = 'nuuuts'"]; // aBlockOrDelegate is informed of changed to "deez"
```

Currently, the best thing I can think of is basically to walk the global object after every eval, which as you can imagine is... sub-optimal :)

The Obj-C interface has no class reference that I can find, so I've been relying on going through the headers, and it seems pretty limited, so I imagine that if it can be done, I will need to go into the WebKit C APIs. Unfortunately my google-fu has led me in circles, or to documentation on V8, or whatever they call Mozilla's JS engine this week.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How would you do this in pure JS?

Comment: Basically you can't, not with certainty anyway. But it seems like something that should be doable from the host application.